# Qt: Create a scrollbar with a shadow one behind that holds the last value

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, scrollbar

I am trying to create a scrollbar that has a slider behind holding the last value saved by the user. To better explain my purpose, I created the image below.

[image: Image showing the desired effect.]

In the image, the slider in the middle is supposed to be holding the last value applied by the user, while the main slider, the one on the top, is free to be dragged. In other words, the one in the middle cannot be selected, and its value is changed to the value of the other one when the user presses a button or something.

So far I have tried the following approaches, with no success:

1. Create a class that inherits from QScrollBar, and add an other QScrollBar inside.

   scrollbar.h

   ```
   #ifndef SCROLLBAR_H
   #define SCROLLBAR_H

   #include <QScrollBar>

   class ScrollBar : public QScrollBar
   {
       Q_OBJECT

       public:
           ScrollBar ( Qt::Orientation orientation, QWidget * parent = 0 );
           void init();
           void update();

       private:
           QScrollBar* subslider;

   };

   #endif // SCROLLBAR_H
   ```

   scrollbar.cpp

   ```
   #include "scrollbar.h"

   ScrollBar::ScrollBar( Qt::Orientation orientation, QWidget * parent ) :
       QScrollBar (orientation, parent) {
       subslider = new QScrollBar(orientation, this);
   }

   void ScrollBar::init() {
       subslider->setMaximum( QScrollBar::maximum() );
       subslider->setMinimum( QScrollBar::minimum() );
       subslider->setFixedSize( QScrollBar::size() );
       subslider->setValue( QScrollBar::minimum() );
       subslider->setEnabled(false);
       subslider->setVisible(true);
   }

   void ScrollBar::update() {
       subslider->setValue( QScrollBar::sliderPosition() );
   }
   ```
2. Create a class that inherits from QScrollBar, and use `paintEvent` to add the other slider.

   scrollbar.h

   ```
   #ifndef SCROLLBAR_H
   #define SCROLLBAR_H

   #include <QScrollBar>
   #include <QPaintEvent>

   class ScrollBar : public QScrollBar
   {
       Q_OBJECT

       public:
           ScrollBar ( Qt::Orientation orientation, QWidget * parent = 0 );
           void update();

       private:
           int scrollbar_pos;

       signals:
       protected:
           void paintEvent( QPaintEvent* event );
   };

   #endif // SCROLLBAR_H
   ```

   scrollbar.cpp

   ```
   #include "scrollbar.h"
   #include <QPainter>

   ScrollBar::ScrollBar( Qt::Orientation orientation, QWidget * parent ) :
       QScrollBar (orientation, parent) {
       scrollbar_pos = 0;
   }

   void ScrollBar::update() {
       subslider_pos = QScrollBar::sliderPosition();
   }

   void ScrollBar::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event) {
       // This calls the base class's paint calls
       QScrollBar::paintEvent(event);
       // The following is painted on top of it
       QPainter p(this);
       /**
        * I think the code here should get the image used to display the slider
        * and put it on the correct position.
        */
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem using a different approach. I used a CSS stylesheet to manually configure the slider and created a button similar to the slider to represent the last saved value. Now the class looks like this.

scrollbar.h

```
#ifndef SCROLLBAR_H
#define SCROLLBAR_H

#include <QSlider>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QPushButton>

class ScrollBar : public QSlider
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        ScrollBar ( QWidget * parent = 0 );
        ~ScrollBar();
        void init();
        void update();

    protected:
        QPushButton* button;

    protected slots:
        void mousePressEvent();
};

#endif // SCROLLBAR_H
```

scrollbar.cpp

```
#include "scrollbar.h"
#include <QPainter>

ScrollBar::ScrollBar( QWidget * parent ) :
    QSlider (Qt::Horizontal, parent) {
    QSlider::setMaximum(100);
    QSlider::setMinimum(0);
    QSlider::setValue(50);
    QSlider::setFixedSize(200, 20);

    button = new QPushButton(this);
    button->setObjectName("slider");
    button->move(0, 3);
    button->setEnabled(true);
    button->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);

    connect(button, SIGNAL(pressed()), this, SLOT(mousePressEvent()));
}

void ScrollBar::update() {
    std::cout << "Called update()" << std::endl;
    // The following moves the false button
    double delta =  QSlider::sliderPosition() /
            (double) (QSlider::maximum() - QSlider::minimum()) *
            (QSlider::width() - 14);
    button->move(delta, 3);
}

void ScrollBar::mousePressEvent() {
    QPoint pos = button->pos();
    pos.setX( pos.x() + 7 );
    pos.setY(6);
    QMouseEvent evt(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, pos, Qt::LeftButton,
                    Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
    QSlider::mousePressEvent(&evt);
}

ScrollBar::~ScrollBar() {
}
```

slider.css

```
QSlider::groove:horizontal {
border: 1px solid #bbb;
background: white;
height: 10px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::sub-page:horizontal {
background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0,    x2: 0, y2: 1,
    stop: 0 #66e, stop: 1 #bbf);
background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0.2, x2: 1, y2: 1,
    stop: 0 #bbf, stop: 1 #55f);
border: 1px solid #777;
height: 10px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::add-page:horizontal {
background: #fff;
border: 1px solid #777;
height: 10px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::handle:horizontal {
background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1,
    stop:0 #eee, stop:1 #ccc);
border: 1px solid #777;
width: 13px;
margin-top: -2px;
margin-bottom: -2px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::handle:horizontal:hover {
background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1,
    stop:0 #fff, stop:1 #ddd);
border: 1px solid #444;
border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::sub-page:horizontal:disabled {
background: #bbb;
border-color: #999;
}

QSlider::add-page:horizontal:disabled {
background: #eee;
border-color: #999;
}

QSlider::handle:horizontal:disabled {
background: #eee;
border: 1px solid #aaa;
border-radius: 4px;
}

QPushButton#slider {
background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1,
    stop:0 #ccc, stop:1 #aaa);
border: 1px solid #777;
max-width: 13px;
min-width: 13px;
max-height: 12px;
min-height: 12px;
border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Adding the widget looks something like this:

```
QFile file("slider.css");
file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QString style = file.readAll();
file.close();

ScrollBar* scroll = new ScrollBar(parent);

parent->setStyleSheet(style);
// or scroll->setStyleSheet(style); if the style should be added only to this widget
```

.
The result looks like this:

[image]

---

I had to connect the button press to pass the mouse event to the slider, since the button is on top of it.

---

**EDIT**

An even cleaner solution is to add transparent scrollbars instead of the push button.

scrollbar.h

```
#ifndef SCROLLBAR_H
#define SCROLLBAR_H

#include <QSlider>
#include <QResizeEvent>

class ScrollBar : public QSlider
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        bool enabled;

        ScrollBar ( QWidget * parent = 0 );
        ~ScrollBar();

        void init();
        void update();

        void setValue(int);
        void setFixedValue(int);

        QSize sizeHint() const;

    protected:
        QSlider* slider_fixed;
        QSlider* slider_top;

        virtual void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *evt);
};

#endif
```

scrollbar.cpp

```
#include "scrollbar.h"
#include <QFile>

ScrollBar::ScrollBar( QWidget * parent ) : QSlider (Qt::Horizontal, parent) {
    QSlider::setMaximum(100);
    QSlider::setMinimum(0);
    QSlider::setValue(50);

    slider_fixed = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal, this);
    slider_fixed->setMaximum( QSlider::maximum() );
    slider_fixed->setMinimum( QSlider::minimum() );
    slider_fixed->setValue( QSlider::minimum() );
    slider_fixed->setObjectName("transparent_fixed");

    slider_top = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal, this);
    slider_top->setMaximum( QSlider::maximum() );
    slider_top->setMinimum( QSlider::minimum() );
    slider_top->setValue( QSlider::sliderPosition() );
    slider_top->setObjectName("transparent_top");

    QFile file("slider.css");
    file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    QString style = file.readAll();
    file.close();

    QSlider::setStyleSheet(style);

    QObject::connect(slider_top, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(setValue(int)));
}

QSize ScrollBar::sizeHint() const {
    return QSize(2000, 20);
}

void ScrollBar::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *evt) {
    int width  = evt->size().width();
    int height = evt->size().height();

    slider_fixed->resize(width, height);
    slider_top->resize(width, height);
}

void ScrollBar::setFixedValue(int value) {
    slider_fixed->setValue( value );
}

void ScrollBar::setValue(int value) {
    slider_top->setValue(value);
}

ScrollBar::~ScrollBar() {
}
```

slider.css

```
QSlider::groove:horizontal {
border: 1px solid #bbb;
background: white;
height: 10px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::sub-page:horizontal {
background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0,    x2: 0, y2: 1,
    stop: 0 #66e, stop: 1 #bbf);
background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0.2, x2: 1, y2: 1,
    stop: 0 #bbf, stop: 1 #55f);
border: 1px solid #777;
height: 10px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::add-page:horizontal {
background: #fff;
border: 1px solid #777;
height: 10px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::handle:horizontal {
background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1,
    stop:0 #eee, stop:1 #ccc);
border: 1px solid #777;
width: 13px;
margin-top: -2px;
margin-bottom: -2px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::handle:horizontal:hover {
background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1,
    stop:0 #fff, stop:1 #ddd);
border: 1px solid #444;
border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider#transparent_fixed::groove:horizontal {
border: none;
background: transparent;
border-radius: 0px;
}

QSlider#transparent_fixed::sub-page:horizontal {
background: transparent;
border: none;
border-radius: 0px;
}

QSlider#transparent_fixed::add-page:horizontal {
background: transparent;
border: none;
border-radius: 0px;
}

QSlider#transparent_fixed::handle:horizontal {
background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1,
    stop:0 #bbb, stop:1 #999);
}

QSlider#transparent_fixed::handle:horizontal:hover {
border: 1px solid #777;
}

QSlider#transparent_top::groove:horizontal {
border: none;
background: transparent;
border-radius: 0px;
}

QSlider#transparent_top::sub-page:horizontal {
background: transparent;
border: none;
border-radius: 0px;
}

QSlider#transparent_top::add-page:horizontal {
background: transparent;
border: none;
border-radius: 0px;
}
```